# String Comparison With RichTextBox Does Not Match

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I write a `String` with the message *"Hello, world."* to a `RichTextBox`.

If I then copy the `RichTextBox` `TextRange` to a new `String` and do a String Comparison, they will not be equal, even though they both have the same text.

I am comparing Strings `message` to `MessageRichTextBox()`.

What is going on? There must be some extra data being copied or excluded from the `RichTextBox`.

---

[image: RTB String Comparison]

---

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbMessage" Margin="10,10,10,50" />

<Button x:Name="btnCompare" Content="Compare" Margin="231,264,211,29" Width="75" Click="btnCompare_Click"/>
```

**C#**

```
String message = "Hello, world.";
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();


// Startup
// Write Message to RichTextBox
//
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    rtbMessage.Document = new FlowDocument(p);

    rtbMessage.BeginChange();
        p.Inlines.Add(new Run(message));
    rtbMessage.EndChange();
}


// Copy RichTextBox to String
//
public String MessageRichTextBox()
{
    FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument(p);
    rtbMessage.Document = fd;

    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentStart,
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    return textRange.Text;
}


// Compare Strings Button
//
private void buttonCompare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (message == MessageRichTextBox())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Strings Match");
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Does Not Match");
    }
}
```

---

**Result**

String message = "Hello, world."
String MessageRichTextBox() = "Hello, world."
Does Not Match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (message.Equals(MessageRichTextBox()))
    MessageBox.Show("Strings Match");
else 
    MessageBox.Show("Does Not Match");
```

Comment: Still gives "Does Not Match".

Comment: Can you put a `messagebox` inside `MessageRichTextBox()` and display the `textRange.Text` before you return it please, then comment with its result @MattMcManis

Comment: I put `MessageBox.Show(textRange.Text);` before the `return`. It gives "Hello, world." https://i.imgur.com/jC4afGi.png

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an extra white space before or after the string? try this: `MessageBox.Show("'" + textRange.Text + "'");`  @MattMcManis

Comment: There's no other white space. It's just like the example. The `"'"` didn't work.

Comment: Wait, the `"'"` may have discovered a LineBreak.

Comment: Not sure if you saw this but inside your rich text box `World` has a capitalized `W` but the message doesnt

Comment: I just forgot to update the W in the example, that wasn't the problem. The RichTextBox was putting a LineBreak in the String. Your `"'"` found it, thanks. I removed it with `return textRange.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");`.